# UTF8: U+00E9 é is split into U+0065 e and U+00B4 ´

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, encoding, diacritics

I'm struggling with some UTF8-Data.

When I open an UTF8-file in hex-view, the **é** is split into two characters (**U+0065 e** and **U+00B4 ´**) instead of using the obvious character **U+00E9 é**.

If I store these data on my database (Note: Collation is set to **German_PhoneBook_CI_AI**)
then it's stored

**Depardieu, Ge´rard (!!)**

instead of :
**Depardieu, Gérard**.

So I'm wondering if the data itself is flawed or what kind of information I am missing.
Let me know if you need any more information coupled with this problem.

The apparent question is: **How can I solve this problem?**

Note:
I tagged this question as C# / VB.NET, because there might be answers where code snippets are useful.

Comment: How was that UTF-8 file created, and what encoding do you use in the database?

Comment: If it is really a UTF8 file then é should be encoded as 0xc3, 0xa9

Comment: There are combining diacritical characters in Unicode, but U+00B4 is none of them. I`d say that encoding is not UTF-8 or it is faulty.

Comment: @MatthewWatson U+00E9 is the equivalent of 0xc3 0xa9. So I guess the file is flawed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website where we parsed the unicode didn't provide proper unicode.